# ReactJs:Trying to get value of a select menu when button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to figure out how for each item rendered, inside that item i want to get the value of the select menu when i click the button. 
i've tried creating a variable inside the render but it's bound to all of the rendered items.

```
export const products = React.createClass({
getInitialState() {
    return {
        prods: [
            {
                "name": "T-Shirt",
                "image_full": "550.jpeg",
                "image_thumb": "415.jpeg",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-S",
                        "name": "Small",
                        "price": 21.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-M",
                        "name": "Medium",
                        "price": 21.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-L",
                        "name": "Large",
                        "price": 21.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-XL",
                        "name": "X-Large",
                        "price": 21.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-2XL",
                        "name": "2X-Large",
                        "price": 23.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-3XL",
                        "name": "3X-Large",
                        "price": 23.95
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "T-Shirt 2",
                "image_full": "550.jpeg",
                "image_thumb": "415.jpeg",
                "options": [
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-S",
                        "name": "Small",
                        "price": 21.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-M",
                        "name": "Medium",
                        "price": 21.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-L",
                        "name": "Large",
                        "price": 21.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-XL",
                        "name": "X-Large",
                        "price": 21.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-2XL",
                        "name": "2X-Large",
                        "price": 23.95
                    },
                    {
                        "sku": "TGT-SHIRT-3XL",
                        "name": "3X-Large",
                        "price": 23.95
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], cart: []
    }
},
render() {
    let prodlist = this.state.prods.map(pp => <div className="col-md-2">
        <img src={pp.image_full} alt={pp.title} width="100%" />
        <select ref="ppt">
            <option value="null" selected>Select Option</option>
            {pp.options.map(opts => <option value={opts.sku}>{opts.name}</option>)}
        </select>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block">ADD TO CART</button>
    </div>
    )
    return (
        <div>
            {prodlist}
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

export default products

Answer (score 0):

You can store selected id (or scu in your example) in `onChange` on `select`

```
onChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({selectedScu: e.target.value});
}
```

And get it from the list on button click

```
options.find(option => option.scu === this.state.selectedScu)
```

Comment: if you do it that way.  wont the state.selectedSku be same for each item?

Comment: You can store selected id in the parent component - this way selectedSku will be unique